# Get number of elements in xml-string-resource-file

Tags: android

I have different xml-string-files in my resources.

One of those files contains different elements for different languages. 
Now I want to get the number of the elements in the xml-file.

I only found the possibilty to iterate through the whole file and count the elements, which would be no problem but seems to be some kind of overkill.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OMG! You defined some string(s) for language X but not for language Y? Did you try to ***use*** the missing strings? The last time I did, there was an exception, "resource not found" or something like that.

If you have translations only for some messages, leave the untranslated messages in English. At least, you will know from the source that some messages are not localized.

Comment: It's difficult to explain, but I know what I am doing ;). I have this file for all languages but the content is not the same. I think I'm going to put the file under res/raw or res/xml and parse it by myself.